# Text, IF and Else Statement, ActionScript

Tags: if-statement, textbox, actionscript, textinput

everyone.

I'm having a bit of an issue with ActionScript. I've created a text box and I want my user to enter an answer in to the text box, IF they get it right it will go to "said" frame, but if then get it wrong it ELSE will go to "said frame".

However I cannot get my if, else statement to work in my code. It seems that once the timeline gets to the ActionScript frame it then takes me to the frame assigned by the else command despite me typing in the correct answer in my text box. Anyone know how to fix this? I've posted my draft of what I have down below. Much appreciated.

[TextInputDraft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNlaW.png)

Comment: Add your code here, not somewhere else. Use the "help" link to see how it works. Be more specific about your problem. What do you want to achieve with the code etc

Comment: Thank you for the tip @SeparateReality.


answer.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, addEntry);

function addEntry(evt:Event):void {

if(answer.text = "78")
{
gotoAndPlay(2789);
}
else 
{
gotoAndPlay(3584);
}

Comment: The comparison operator is ==, not =. Also, you should **edit** your post and format script as code, because the comments does not support code formatting and it is next to unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you use the [comparison operator](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#equality) in your if statement. Right now, you are *setting* the text property inside your if statement instead of comparing.

You need to change this line:

```
if (answer.text = "78") {
```

to this:

```
if (answer.text == "78") {
```